# JS: Convert URL into its simplest form

Tags: javascript

I am building a NodeJS application that can store URLs in a database. I want to use the URLs as a primary key, to avoid duplicates being stored. In order to do this I need the url to be in the simplest form possible, removing extra slashes, arguments and prefixes.

How do I convert all of the URLs listed below into the same string as the first URL listed? Is there a way to do this safely, to account for other variations I might have not listed below?

[website.com/coolpage/938921](http://website.com/coolpage/938921)

https://website.com/coolpage/938921/

https://www.website.com/coolpage/938921/

http://website.com/coolpage/938921/

https://website.com/coolpage/938921/

https://website.com/coolpage/938921/?awesome=1

https://website.com/coolpage/938921?awesome=1

https:///website.com//coolpage//938921//

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you'll probably need to do a decent amount of regex and string matching :/

Comment: Is it a web app? If so which library do you use as a framework?

Comment: I am making an electron app with NodeJs. All URLs need to match the first string listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard Node.js  [`url`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url) module.

**Solution:**

```
require('url');

function getBaseUrl(url){
    const u = new URL(url);
    const result =`${u.host}${u.pathname}`
        .split('//').join('/')
        .replace('www.', '');

    // cut off the trailing '/' character from the result
    if (result.length && result[result.length - 1] === '/')
        return result.substring(0, result.length - 1)

    return result;
}
```

**Test:**

```
const urls = [
    "https://website.com/coolpage/938921/",
    "https://www.website.com/coolpage/938921/",
    "http://website.com/coolpage/938921/",
    "https://website.com/coolpage/938921/",
    "https://website.com/coolpage/938921/?awesome=1",
    "https://website.com/coolpage/938921?awesome=1",
    "https:///website.com//coolpage//938921//"
    ];

for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    const u = getBaseUrl(urls[i]);
    console.log(`${i}: ${u}`);
}
```

**Console output:**

```
0: website.com/coolpage/938921
1: website.com/coolpage/938921
2: website.com/coolpage/938921
3: website.com/coolpage/938921
4: website.com/coolpage/938921
5: website.com/coolpage/938921
6: website.com/coolpage/938921
```

[Live example on runkit.com](https://runkit.com/develax/stackoverflow-convert-url-into-its-simplest-form)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the function to achieve what you want:

```js
function convertURL(url) {
 var urlParts = url.split('/')
 var finalURL = ''
 urlParts.forEach((p, i) => {
  if(finalURL.length == 0){
   if(p.includes('.com')){
    finalURL += p
   }
  }

  else if (p.length > 0 && i < urlParts.length - 1){
   finalURL += '/' + p
  }
 })

 return finalURL
}

var url = convertURL('https://website.com/coolpage/938921/?awesome=1')
console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.replace` with `RegExp` `\/+` to match one or more forward slash characters `/` replaced with single `/` and `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+(?=\/+)\/[a-z0-9]+(?=\/+)\/[a-z0-9]+/ig` to match hostname and pathname of URL.

```js
let urls = ["https://website.com/coolpage/938921/", "https://www.website.com/coolpage/938921/", "http://website.com/coolpage/938921/", "https://website.com/coolpage/938921/", "https://website.com/coolpage/938921/?awesome=1", "https://website.com/coolpage/938921?awesome=1", "https:///website.com//coolpage//938921//"];

let _URL = "website.com/coolpage/938921";

let replaceForwardSlashes = /\/+/g;

let matchHostAndPathNames = /[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+(?=\/+)\/[a-z0-9]+(?=\/+)\/[a-z0-9]+/ig;

let matchedURLS = urls.map(url => url.replace(replaceForwardSlashes,'/').match(matchHostAndPathNames));

console.log(matchedURLS, new Set(...matchedURLS).size === 1, matchedURLS.every(u => u == _URL));
```